# How to find processes with identical name currently running, using a batchfile

Tags: batch-file, process, double

How to find processes with identical name currently running, using a batchfile. And if there are more than one process with same name like myprocess.exe than it should kill it all. If there is only one process myperocess.exe than it should leave it.

Comment: This is done way easier in PowerShell. Find multiple process names `Get-Process|group name -no|? count -gt 1` Stop specified multiple process name (here firefox) `Get-Process firefox|group name|? count -gt 1|%{$_.Group|Stop-Process}`

Answer (score 0):

list them, count them and if the counter is greater than one, kill them:

```
for /f %a in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fo csv ^|find /c /v ""') do if %a gtr 1 taskkill /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe"
```

(this is command line syntax. To use it in a batchfile, replace every `%a` with  `%%a`)